# Flushing of cout prior to reading input using cin .. why?

Tags: c++

Why does cout has to be flushed before cin starts reading? Aren't they of different buffer? I can have reading of input into a buffer while same time putting it on output buffer (before flushing) .. 2 different buffers. I am confused here.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't have to be flushed. By default the streams are `tied` together so that when you do things like:

```
cout << "Enter your name:";
cin >> name;
```

the prompt appears before the input starts - this is just a  convenience feature. However, you can untie them:

```
cin.tie( static_cast<ostream*>(0) );
```

following which cout will not (necessarily) be flushed before input is performed on cin.

Comment: What if i do wanna maintain the 'Enter your name:" in the buffer without displaying it and meantime i wanna read?

Comment: @yapkm01 Like I said - untie them. It seems unlikely you actually do want to do this, however.

Comment: @yapkm01: If you think this answers your question best, you should accept it.

Comment: @sbi Another better answer might come along from someone in a different timezone. Please do not pressure people (especially on my behalf) to accept.

Comment: @Neil: As I understand it, you can always change the accepted answer later. If an answer fits and answers the question, why not accept it? Anyway, I wasn't trying to pressure. I just thought that someone with a rep of 6 might not know the rules well enough and could live with being hinted at them.

Answer (score 7):

The canonical example is this:

```
 std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
 std::string name;
 std::cin >> name;
```

You do want to see the prompt before the input, that's why those two streams are tied together.